# How to integrate a binomial function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, binomial-coefficients, binomial-ideals

> Evaluate the following integral.
> $$\int_{0}^1\displaystyle{207 \choose 7}{x^{200}(1-x)^7}\, dx$$

---

My attempt was a lengthy one. I opened the integral using binomial expansion and got $7$ different terms which I integrated but one thing that strikes me was since the integral is from $0$ to $1$ and if I replace $x$ by $1-x$ and add the two integrals I might end up with something simpler.

---

I am not able to implement it or rather I'm struck with it so any help to make this integral simpler.

---

Edit l know it can be solved by by parts. My query is

---

$$\int_{0}^1\displaystyle{207 \choose 7}{x^{200}(1-x)^7}\, dx$$ replacing x by 1-x
$$\int_{0}^1\displaystyle{207 \choose 7}{(1-x)^{200}(x)^7}\, dx$$
On adding

---

2I=$$\int_{0}^1\displaystyle{207 \choose 7}{x^{200}(1-x)^7}+\,^1\displaystyle{207 \choose 200}{x^{200}(1-x)^7} dx$$,
Now since they have become two equidistant terms of binomial expansion (1-x)^2007 can I directly write the sum

Comment: Indeed I would open up the parentheses. In other words, I would just integrate
$$
\int x^{200} \cdot(-x^7 +7x^6  - 21x^5  +35x^4 -35x^3 + 21x^2 -7x +1)\, dx
$$

Comment: As for the $\binom{207}{7}$... that is just a number.  I'd move that outside.

Comment: @Anusha : sure that the integral is not in $\int_0^1$?? If yes you can solve it immediately with beta function leading to $\frac{1}{208}$ as a result

Comment: @tommik Pretty sure the exercice is in fact to discover the induction relation for beta function. OP: thus call $B(m,n)=\int x^m(1-x)^n$ and integrate by parts so as to decrease $n$.

Comment: Anusha had written $\int_0^1,$ but in the edit by @MattiP. it's changed to $\int_0^7.$ So I assume that it should really be $\int_0^1.$

Comment: I have edited the post to restore the integration limits to $0,1$, as was originally written.  It appears that the change in the limits was an editing error.  As others have remarked, with the limits of $0,1$ this computation follows easily from standard properties of the Beta function.

Comment: Yeah sorry about the typo.

Comment: @JMoravitz Maybe it’s a misprint and she wants something like  $\int_{0}^{1}{207 \choose x}\,\mathrm{d}x$.

Comment: @FelixMarin its she and it's not a misprint I've edited the same

Comment: @JMoravitz I want to use this no. In way to simplify the integral

Comment: @Anusha Fixed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_0^1x^{200}(1-x)^7dx=\frac{1}{208}$$

---

This belong to series $$(x+(1-x))^207=1$$

.there are total 208 terms in the series since there are 104 pairs whose sum is equal to mid two terms . So total 104 terms with equal sum. In which the integral we want I.e 2I exists as one of the pair

---

1= 104×2I   giving I as 1/208

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure the text is correct. Assuming that the integral is

$$\binom{207}{7}\int_0^1x^{200}(1-x)^7dx=\frac{207!}{7!200!}\frac{\Gamma(201)\Gamma(8)}{\Gamma(201+8)}=\frac{207!}{7!200!}\frac{200!7!}{208!}=\frac{1}{208}$$

If the text is correct, $\int_0^7 f(x)dx \approx -2.86\times 10^{185}$...(result by the calculator....of course) good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Folllowing @zwim's hint, by parts

$$I:=\int_0^1x^{200}(1-x)^7\,dx=\left.\frac{x^{201}(1-x)^7}{201}\right|_0^1+\frac7{201}\int_0^1x^{201}(1-x)^6\,dx\\=\frac7{201}\int_0^1x^{201}(1-x)^6\,dx.$$

Similarly,

$$I=\frac{7\cdot6}{201\cdot202}\int_0^1x^{202}(1-x)^5\,dx=\cdots\\\frac{7\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1}{201\cdot202\cdot203\cdot204\cdot205\cdot206\cdot207}\int_0^1x^{207}\,dx.$$

Comment: Thanks but I know this method as specified in the question

Comment: @Anusha: Haha, this was added later, thank you. Not counting that you explained that you tried another method.

Answer (score 2):

Using the incomplete beta function
$$I_{m,n}=\binom{m+n}{n}\int x^m(1-x)^n\,dx=\binom{m+n}{n}B_x(m+1,n+1)$$
$$J_{m,n}=\binom{m+n}{n}\int_0^1 x^m(1-x)^n\,dx=\binom{m+n}{n}\left(B_1(m+1,n+1)-B_0(m+1,n+1)\right)$$ Going from beta to gamma function
$$J_{m,n}=\binom{m+n}{n}\frac{\Gamma (m+1) \Gamma (n+1)}{\Gamma (m+n+2)}=\frac 1 {m+n+1}$$